# Mercurial Log by file extension

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to find a way to generate a HG log file with history for just certain file types (like *.java). I need the diffs with the log...but again only the .java files.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this:

`hg log --patch --rev "modifies('**.java')"`

See [`hg help revsets`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) and [`hg help filesets`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/filesets) for information on how to target Mercurial command using specific rules.